# How-to run Selenium tests written in PHP from the command-line

Tags: php, command-line, selenium

I am trying to run Selenium tests (PHP) from the command-line. 
I can only find ways to run HTML tests on stackoverflow.

java -jar selenium-server.jar -htmlSuite "*firefox" "http://10.8.100.106" "C:\mytestsuite.html" "C:\results.html"

Is there a way to do the same for a PHP testsuite?

Currently I only know how to run them from my Netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just run your PHPUnit suite the way you normally would if you were not using Se. See http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.2/en/organizing-test-suites.html for further information.

Comment: Thanx! Obviously this was the first thing I tried, but it came up with all kind of weird errors and wouldn't run, so I thought it was not the right way. Errors are gone since I specified the location of an include file more explicitly. Probably a windows vs. unix problem.